# What is the type of a string added to a property of a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, typeerror

### ISSUE

I wanted to fix this error `Uncaught TypeError: ('<li>' + $input.val() + '</li>').appendTo(ourList) is not a function`.

I've been playing around a lot and I don't even remember how I ended up adding the `$` in front of the *string* (?) inside the parentheses. It worked but I don't know why...

---

### MY REASEARCH

From my understanding based off of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function) I got that error in my code because **the function was called on the wrong object.**

Then the [API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/#appendTo-target) says that this function can be called on any of those
`Selector | htmlString | Element |  Array | jQuery object`

---

So I fixed the error when I called the .appenTo method on a jQ object

```
$('<li>' + $input.val() + '</li>').appendTo(ourList); // jQuery object
```

But I got this error from calling the .appenTo method on an htmlString,  though that should be fine... 
I mean, this bit of code `('<li>' + $input.val() + '</li>')` Is a string, isn't it?

```
('<li>' + $input.val() + '</li>').appendTo(ourList); // htmlString???
```

---

### MY QUESTION

What is up with this bit of code `('<li>' + $input.val() + '</li>')` that it caused the error? Is it a string or not?

Comment: yes it is string

Comment: It is a string and strings dont have a `appendTo` method.

Comment: Some of the code you posted don't have $ in front so you're trying to execute `appendTo` on string. that method can be accessed only on jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then the API Docs says that this function can be called on any of those Selector | htmlString | Element | Array | jQuery object

Nope it says that the `target` parameter takes these types, so you can do:

```
jQObject
   .appendTo("#test") // selector
   .appendTo("<div></div>") // html string
   .appendTo(document.body) // element
   .appendTo([document.body]) // array
   .appendTo($()) // jQObject
```

But it can only be called on a jquery object, not on a plain string.

Comment: That's great I get it now! have a nice day +1

Comment: @aduku glad to help, you too :)